# How to make homepage slider image not scale mobile?

Tags: mobile, slider

My current homepage banner scales down to mobile and the image & text shrinks to a size that's unreadable.

How can you make it so that after it scales to a certain point the image stops scaling and it just cuts off the width of the image?

My site: www.riotsociety.com

Example site: sunglass.la

Comment: Where is the code snippet, where you need help? Here, read this -> [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your CSS files. 
This will make your slider 70% of the viewport height. So it will take 70% of any device's height.

this will solve the image problem

`.fullwidthbanner-container {
  height: 70vh; //please work around this value
}`

Now the thing is that the Slider's JS is calculating and giving to each element sizes and styling's. 
The buttons content becomes 3px in size on mobiles.

Now I see 2 solutions for this.

- Read the documentation of the slider library or plugin if there is any and try to make it not give heights and values for the responsive part of the slider and just do it by your own. You'll need a little bit of CSS.
- Or, let it as it is and write on top CSS.

Do you have access to the code? Or it's just a shopify website? I can see that the slider is owl_carrousel